# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 53 when accessing google spreadsheets

Tags: java

Trying to access google spreadsheets. However, the above error is getting displayed. I have created the .p12 file using the client id from developers.google.com. Please let me know what is the issue. Complete error is as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream
>   rejects tag type 53   at
>   sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:82)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:115)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(GoogleCredential.java:670)
>     at testExcelAuth.testExcelAuth.main(testExcelAuth.java:27)

Given below is the code I am using:

```
package testExcelAuth;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetFeed;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;


public class testExcelAuth {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList scopes = new ArrayList();
    scopes.add(0, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    scopes.add(1, "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
        .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
        .setServiceAccountId("rkulkarni@securet.in")
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(newFile(
       ".\\src\\testExcelAuth\\key.p12"))
        .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

    credential.refreshToken();

    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("tmp");
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

    // Define the URL to request. This should never change.
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

    // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
        SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
    int i = 0;
    for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
      ++i;
      System.out.println(spreadsheet.getId());
    }
    System.out.println("Done " + i);   
  }
}
```

Comment: after creation have u closed the file. also check if u have read/write access on the file. sometimes files created by third parties have some settings making it inaccessible

Answer (score 0):

Solution: use a different browser, preferably Google Chrome.

Ran into the same error, and it turns out downloading the key using Internet Explorer (or Microsoft Edge) is the problem. I logged into my dev console from chrome, downloaded the key file again and lo and behold it works.

I suspect the reason is that on IE it gets downloaded in a base-64 encoded format, whereas in Chrome, etc. it is preserved as a binary.